# Implementing short lived Jwt with Refresh Token with Blazor

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor, blazor-client-side

We are currently developing a `Blazor` app which is secured using short lived (10 minute) Jwt with Refresh Tokens.

Currently we have the Jwt implemented and through the Blazor server side web api can login, generate the Jwt and generate the refresh token.

From the client side I have used the following link;

[Authentication With client-side Blazor](https://github.com/chrissainty/AuthenticationWithClientSideBlazor)

and extended the `ApiAuthenticationStateProvider.cs` as follows;

```
public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

    public ApiAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
        var refreshToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("refreshToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(refreshToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        var userResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync<UserModel>("api/accounts/user", savedToken);

        if(userResponse.HasError)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync<LoginResponse>("api/login/refreshToken", new RefreshTokenModel { RefreshToken = refreshToken });

            //check result now
            if (!response.HasError)
            {
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", response.Result.AccessToken);
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("refreshToken", response.Result.RefreshToken);

                userResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync<UserModel>("api/accounts/user", response.Result.AccessToken);
            }

        }

        var identity = !userResponse.HasError ? new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userResponse.Result.Email) }, "apiauth") : new ClaimsIdentity();

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) }, "apiauth"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
}
```

So if the Jwt fails the first time we try to renew with the refresh token.

The code above is working, however the first issue i found is, if I then navigate to the `/fetchData` test end point (which is protected with the `[Authorize]` attribute). The page initially runs fine and sends the Jwt in the header. However, if i then `f5` and refresh the page I get a 401 unauthorized on the `/fecthData` endpoint, i.e. on the code;

```
@code {
    WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts");
    }
}
```

Now if to get around this I can manually add the Jwt form localStorage to the header (in my case I use an extension method);

```
public static async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> GetAsync<T>(
        this HttpClient httpClient, string url, string token)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        return await BuildResponse<T>(response);
    }
```

However, the second issue I have here is that if the Jwt expires during this call I would need to call to use the refresh token to get a new Jwt.

Is there a way I can do this do this with middleware to avoid having to check for a 401 on each call and then renewing the token this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So often, we are thinking on Blazor as an MVC but it is not. It's more like a desktop app running inside browser. I use JWT and renewing tokens in this way: after login, I have an infinite loop that is pinging backend and keeping the session and renewing the tokens. Simplifying:

```
class JWTAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private bool IsLogedIn = false;
    private CustomCredentials credentials = null;
    // private ClaimsPrincipal currentClaimsPrincipal = null; (optinally)
    public Task Login( string user, string password )
    {
         credentials = go_backend_login_service( user, password );
         // do stuff with credentials and claims
         // I raise event here to notify login
         keepSession( );
    }
    public Task Logout(  )
    {
         go_bakcend_logout_service( credentials );
         // do stuff with claims
         IsLogedIn = false;
         // I raise event here to notify logout
    }
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        // make a response from credentials or currentClaimsPrincipal
    }
    private async void KeepSession()
    {
        while(IsLogedIn)
        {
            credentials = go_backend_renewingJWT_service( credentials );
            // do stuff with new credentials: check are ok, update IsLogedIn, ...
            // I raise event here if server says logout
            await Task.Delay(1000);  // sleep for a while.
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to register component by DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other services added here ...

    // One JWTAuthenticationStateProvider for each connection on server side.
    // A singleton for clientside.
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
                       JWTAuthenticationStateProvider>();
}
```

This is just one idea, you should to think about it and adapt it to your own solution.

More about Authentication and Authorization on [github SteveSandersonMS/blazor-auth.md](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/175a08dcdccb384a52ba760122cd2eda)

Comment: Thanks for that. How does the pipeline work than in regards to calling when using an in page Api call? As I am finding that after a logging in and calling an in page `.GetJsonAsync()` i get an `403` returned?

Comment: 403? It looks like a new issue unrelated with current one. Just post a new question with all details. Don't forget to debug server side to isolate error.

Comment: I think the issues is that the view isn't wrapped `AuthorizeView` attribute, hence the JwtStateProvider is not being hit. I'll raise another question for this. So back on subject regarding your implementation, do you use the expiry of the JWT to determine the `Task.Delay(expiry)` or would you just poll? also, once you get a 403 returned do you try once with the refresh and then trigger a logout? Or is that part of your `go_backend_renewingJWT_service` call?

Comment: This is just one idea, you should to think about it and adapt it to your own solution. You should to renew jwt before it expires, then, pooling `go_backend_renewingJWT_service` with `Task.Delay(expiry - X )` is the trick. Create your own logic to deal with backend errors (no Internet connection, retries, ... )

Comment: Hi @daniherrera where you say "// I raise event here to notify login" what code do you implement there? Thanks a lot

Comment: @VAAA, just a simple [event pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/).